# GWT-RPC Unable to access servlet

Tags: java, gwt, build, build-process, gwt-rpc

I integrated my gwt module in to existing web application and deployed on jboss.

when I trying to hit gwt_servlet then I am getting error message on failure method of asynccallback i.e. 
The requested resource (/warFileName/GWTAPPS/myGwtModuleName/GWTServletName) is not available.

My war contain is as follows

**GWTAPPS** :

**myGwtModuleName**(folder) : (folder contains -->)advanced,css,gwt,images folder and some *.cache.png files myGwtModule.html,   myGwtModule.css

**WEB-INF** -> **deploy** - **myGwtModuleName**

I copied compiled gwt_servlet file into /warFileName/GWTAPPS/myGwtModuleName/ still getting same error i.e resource not available.

Is it necessary to crate WEB-INF/classes(copied *.class file) folder into myGwtModuleName ?.
like warfilename\GWTAPPS\mygwtmodule\WEB-INF\classes

Also getting sometime exception in deployment
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RemoteService

**gwt_servlet entry made in web.xml # **

**This web.xml not present in gwtmodule is this problem ?**

> < servlet>
>   < servlet-name>GWTServletName< /servlet-name>
>   < servlet-class>ui.mygwtmodule.server.BasicUpdateServiceImpl < /servlet-class>
>   < /servlet> < servlet-mapping >
>
> ```
> < servlet-name>GWTServletName< /servlet-name>
> < url-pattern>/GWTServletName< /url-pattern>
> < /servlet-mapping>
> ```

also used url pattern like myGwtModuleName/GWTServletName

**RemoteServiceRelativePath added in BasicUpdateService**

> @RemoteServiceRelativePath("GWTServletName")
>
> public interface BasicUpdateService extends RemoteService

**Created a remote service proxy to talk to the server-side GWTMassUpdate service.**

> private final BasicUpdateServiceAsync basicUpdateService =
>   GWT           .create(BasicUpdateService.class);

**Server call**

> basicMassUpdateService.makeServreCall("vaibhav", new AsyncCallback() {

```
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String result) {
                      Window.alert("Result = "+result);                         
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                         Window.alert("On Failure  :"+caught);
                        //  No resource available :-|
                    }
                });
```

Any help or guidance in this matter would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

"Is it necessary to crate WEB-INF/classes(copied *.class file) folder into myGwtModuleName ?"

Yes.

Why arent you using maven or ant for the deployment and build steps of your projects? You loose much time by doing it by hand, and it is more error prone, like these errors.

Id suggest you invest in packaging the gwt application in your war using maven or ant, and focus on developing the gwt application.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're doing some nasty things, deployment should be as easy as copying the whole "war" folder around.

Note: you can safely exclude `WEB-INF/deploy` from the process, as it's only needed for stacktrace deobfuscation, if you setup "remote logging" with the `java.util.logging` client-side emulation)